# issue with certbot to generate a ssl certificate

Tags: ssl

I have some issues to generate a new certificate with certbot. i use certbot 0.10.2 and I want to upgrade it and Acme2 but I have some error when I type `sudo certbot certonly --apache`:

> Could not choose appropriate plugin: The requested apache plugin does not appear to be installed
> The requested apache plugin does not appear to be installed

Answer (score 4):

Try install python3-certbot-apache